# Accurate control of navigation and menus in Microsoft Access 2013 using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've created an admin window in a security level driven MS Access database.  This admin tab is presented to the user when determined that their security is either 1, admin or 2, user.

To cut to the chase, I've created a 'toggle button' (doesn't quite work the way I intended, but it does the trick - well sort of) It's in beta mode for me until I can understand the quirks.

The toggle button says "Hide Menus" which pertains to the navigation, tables, queries... essentially everything that a user can do to accidentally get into the VBA, design, or queries and unravel anything.

When the toggle button is clicked again, it restores all of the above.

However, even though it works, I'm not certain what factors come into play because one setting happens immediately (The Ribbon) and then I don't see the other settings take place until I restart Access.

Here's my code for the button:

```
Private Sub cmdToggleHide_Click()
    Select Case Me.cmdToggleHide.Caption

    Case "Show Menus"
        Call EnableSetProperty(True)
        Me.cmdToggleHide.Caption = "Hide Menus"
    Case "Hide Menus"
        Call EnableSetProperty(False)
        Me.cmdToggleHide.Caption = "Show Menus"
    End Select
End Sub

Public Function EnableSetProperty(bTrueFalse As Boolean)
On Error GoTo ThisError

'True means show all of access

If bTrueFalse = True Then
     DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes


Else
     DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo

End If

    SetProperties "StartUpShowDBWindow", dbBoolean, bTrueFalse ' Display Database Window
    SetProperties "StartUpShowStatusBar", dbBoolean, bTrueFalse 'Status Bar
    SetProperties "AllowFullMenus", dbBoolean, bTrueFalse 'Access Full Menus
    SetProperties "AllowSpecialKeys", dbBoolean, bTrueFalse 'F11, ALT F11, etc.
    SetProperties "AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, bTrueFalse 'Shift Key Override on loading
    SetProperties "AllowShortcutMenus", dbBoolean, bTrueFalse 'Access Shortcut Menus. May be too severe
    SetProperties "AllowToolbarChanges", dbBoolean, bTrueFalse 'Prevent Changes
    SetProperties "AllowBreakIntoCode", dbBoolean, bTrueFalse 'Code Access'

Exit Function




ThisError:

MsgBox Err.Description

Exit Function

End Function



Public Function SetProperties(strPropName As String, varPropType As Variant, varPropValue As Variant) As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_SetProperties

Dim db As Database, prop As Property
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Properties(strPropName) = varPropValue
SetProperties = True

Set db = Nothing

Exit_SetProperties:

     Exit Function

Err_SetProperties:

     If Err = 3270 Then 'Property not found'

         Set prop = db.CreateProperty(strPropName, varPropType, varPropValue)
         db.Properties.Append prop
         Resume Next

     Else
         SetProperties = False
         MsgBox "Runtime Error # " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbLf & Err.Description
         Resume Exit_SetProperties

     End If

End Function
```

The first quirky thing that happens when I click the "Hide Menus" button (intending to 'arm' it or secure it) is that the ribbon up top disappears immediately.  And I wouldn't mind if this setting actually took, but for the rest of the settings to 'take' I have to close the database and re-open it again.

When I reopen it, now the navigation pain is hidden and forms cannot be 'right-clicked' to access 'Design View' and holding down 'Shift' does not by-pass the start-up. However, the ribbon is now back. I don't think I'm missing anything.  This isn't so bad, because what is accessible on the ribbon is pretty harmless.  But I wonder why it comes back.

In order to Un-Arm the system, of course you have to be logged in as an Admin, in which case you still have access to the 'Admin' Tab and the 'Hide/Show' Menus Toggle button. And since I didn't sync the toggle button with a value in a table, so that it reflects the current state, the button still says "Hide" even though it would be nice if it said "Show" at this point - so no biggie, I just click hide once and the button says "Show" so then I click show, shut Access down and voila, navigation and all settings are back to normal.  Why haven't I synced the button with a value in the table?  Because I can't nail down why these settings are out of sync.  It gets even more complicated when I try to have different settings for different users utilizing, say, a checkbox in a table.

So fine. It's workable.

But I'd like to get it working so that it works the way the interface layout suggests it should work.  If I have to notify the user that the settings won't take place till it is restarted, fine.  But I definitely want to know what's going on with the ribbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The ribbon

My guess: if hiding the ribbon would "stick" beyond Access sessions, it would make Access (with *every* database, not just the one that hid the ribbon) pretty much unusable for anyone who doesn't know the counter-spell. Just imagine all the support calls. :o
So the ribbon is always shown when restarting Access.

To always have it hidden, you need to save the Show/Hide state in a table, and if it's "Hide", execute `DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo` in a function that is called from your **AutoExec** macro.

2) The other settings

These are settings that can also be set via `File -> Options -> Current Database`. If you set them there, Access informs you that you will have to close and reopen the database to make them effective.

So this is normal and by design.

Comment: Thank you this will help me make sure I the feature is synchronized.

Comment: Is there different way to manage the "Other settings"  For example, what if I wanted the database window only to be available for admins and never for users?  I see a problem with the restart issue because it seems to affect both.